# dynamic autocomplete textview displayes slowly,how to display faster?

Tags: android

I have written some code for autocompletetextview in custom dialog box.When typing some text that text dynamically search into the hashmap.This hashmap is with large lines of text.It works.But slowly giving me result.

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView)searchDialog.findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    if(searchText.getText()!=null){
    //                  searchString = searchText.getText().toString().trim();
                    String[] autoList = getAutoCompletWords(searchText.getText().toString().trim());
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,autoList);
                    searchText.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

private String[] getAutoCompletWords(String text){
        Set<String> wordsSet = new TreeSet<String>();
        Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b"+text+"\\w+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = wordPattern.matcher(bookContentMap.values().toString());
        while(matcher.find()){
            wordsSet.add(matcher.group());
        }
        String[] wordsArray = wordsSet.toArray(new String[0]);
        return wordsArray;
    }
```

If I take thread for above code it is giving me thread handler exception.Please give me an idea for quick response of list on autocomplettext.

Rajendar Are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know for sure which bits are fast and which are slow, you need to use [Android's profiler](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html). Here are two things worth investigating, they're probably the largest resource drain:

1. You're compiling a regular expression each time a key is pressed, this is very slow. A better option would be to populate a database and query it instead.
2. You're creating both a TreeSet and an Array each time a key is pressed, which probably hurts.
3. Converting bookContentMap's values to a String is probably quite processor intensive. Consider caching this value.

Comment: Actually iam using treeset for sorting the items and meanwhile avoiding the duplicates

Comment: @user486216 Oh okay. Creating the string is also probably quite intensive. I'll edit and add that too